# Задача перебора значений

Tags: c++, циклы, перебор

Попалась следующая задача. Имеется входное значение частоты `Fin` и выходное `Fout`. `Fin`, попадая на вход некоторого устройства, проходит через некоторое количество делителей и умножителей (для конкретики `div1, div2, mult1, mult2`). Т.е. выходная `Fout=Fin*mult1*mult2/div1/div2`. Сначала просят вывести всю сетку выходных частот (по конкретной входной), зачем написать gui, которая подбирала бы по входной и выходной частотам эти коэффициенты.

Однако есть 2 сложности:

1. Значения `Fin`, `Fout` могут быть нецелыми (тогда как коэффициенты целые).
2. При переборе всех вариантов значений коэффициентов (для построения сетки) получается просто огромное число (опять же, конкретные диапазоны: `div1[1:4095], div2[1:4094], mult1[1:2], mult2[8:65535]`.

Понятно, что задачу с подбором можно решить путем поиска НОДа и последовательных переборов каждого из делителей (`Fout/(mult1*mult2)=Fin/(div1*div2`). Однако, как применить эту оптимизацию для случая нецелых чисел - не совсем понятно (ограничиваться конкретной точностью e?).
При этом сетку частот строить вообще непонятно как: получается, что для такой (казалось бы простой) задачи придется потратить порядка 1,5 часов, крутясь в циклах (а это явно не кошерно).

Comment: С нецелостью можно бороться очень просто - домножить обе частоты, чтобы нецелость ушла.

Comment: а вот как сетку построить, не в курсе?

Comment: сетка выходных частот (по конкретной входной) - можно подробнее?